# Is it possible to combine multiple cells into one while also omitting empty cells?

Tags: excel

Is it possible to combine cells in one 'Outcome Cell' while simultaneously omitting any cell that is blank?

Below is an image of the desired outcome. Currently I'm having to use =CONCATENATE to get this outcome but then I have to go through it to remove all of the blank cells manually (with over 50 columns and 1000 rows this takes a long time).

[image: Google sheets screenshot]

Also is a link to the spreadsheet for you to see:

[Excel spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pjdz6NuzJqNuIRjtF_qnAm2S9UjYfpXb-zRF7xSFMvE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you use a version of Excel that supports `TEXTJOIN()` ?

Comment: I'm using Google Sheets which I don't believe has TEXTJOIN() as a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
IF(NOT(ISEMPTY(A2)), A$1 & ": " & A2 & CHAR(10), "") & IF(…
```

EDIT:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)), A$1 & ": " & A2 & CHAR(10), "") & 
 IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B2)), B$1 & ": " & B2 & CHAR(10), "") & 
 IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C2)), C$1 & ": " & C2 & CHAR(10), "") &
 IF(NOT(ISBLANK(D2)), D$1 & ": " & D2, "")
```

All in one line. ISEMPTY is the VBA variant of the worksheet function ISBLANK.

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(A3="","","Size: "&A3&CHAR(10)),IF(B3="","","Material: "&B3&CHAR(10)),IF(C3="","","Colour: "&CHAR(10)),IF(D3="","","Weight: "&D3))
```

*Note: make sure you have text wrap enabled on cells that contain line breaks.*

Answer (score 1):

This formula should help you:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2));CONCATENATE($A$1;":";" ";A2);"");CHAR(10);IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B2));CONCATENATE($B$1;":";" ";B2);"");CHAR(10);IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C2));CONCATENATE($C$1;":";" ";C2);"");CHAR(10);IF(NOT(ISBLANK(D2));CONCATENATE($D$1;":";" ";D2);""))
```

Take a look in my spreedsheet:
[Excel](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12hljTZ_DWNS4XtVue6ECcihKUVSFDPmknpJaSGTjt-4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Use TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF(A2:D2<>"",$A$1:$D$1&": "&A2:D2,""))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]